# SQL Server error msg

Tags: sql-server, triggers

This is my trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgEmployee 
ON EmployeeAudit
FOR INSERT
AS
    DECLARE @empNumber CHAR(8)
    DECLARE @SSN CHAR(9)
    DECLARE @firstName VARCHAR(25)
    DECLARE @lastName VARCHAR(25)
    DECLARE @address VARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @state CHAR(2
    DECLARE @zip CHAR(5)
    DECLARE @job VARCHAR(50)

    INSERT INTO EmployeeAudit 
    VALUES (@empNumber, @SSN, @firstName, @lastName, @address, @state, @zip, @job)
GO
```

When I try to execute it, I get this error:

> Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 189
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@empNumber"

Comment: Line 189? That kind of implies that there's more code. Other things I noticed: @state is missing an end-parenthesis. Also, while all of these variables are declared, they're never set to anything.

Answer (score 2):

You trigger implementation have issues. Instead of reading from the variables you should be reading it from the `Inserted` table.

Following are the existing issues.

Issue with variable declaration.

```
declare @state Char(2
```

Above declaration should be closed properly. Change it to

```
declare @state Char(2)
```

You should also specify the columns when you are using insert.

```
INSERT INTO [TABLE_NAME](COL1,COL2,COL3... COLN)
VALUES(@V1,@V2,@V3...@VN)
```

Ideally your trigger should look like following code.

```
INSERT INTO employeeaudit 
            (empnumber, 
             ssn, 
             firstname, 
             lastname, 
             address, 
             state, 
             zip, 
             job) 
SELECT I.empnumber, 
       I.ssn, 
       I.firstname, 
       I.lastname, 
       I.address, 
       I.state, 
       I.zip, 
       I.job 
FROM   inserted I
```